# Heroku app + 1and1 domains - Custom domain name switches back to default heroku app's domain on click within the web app

Tags: domains, dns, heroku, 1and1

**The issue**

Hey guys, I'm having some issues concerning my website ( http://colegiojeffersontoday.com ). The issue is that although the custom domain works upon first entering the website, for some reason, the domain reverts back to the default heroku app domain whenever you click a link within the website itself. http://desolate-ocean-81838.herokuapp.com.

**Regarding the DNS settings**

In terms of DNS settings, all I did was add the domains colegiojeffersontoday.com and news.colegiojeffersontoday.com to heroku cli. On the 1and1 domain manager I edited the DNS by adding the subdomain "news" to apply a cname to it. The idea is that the root domain redirects to the subdomain which has the cname linked to it. Apologies if that sounds confusing.

Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

You are using Wordpress. You should look up on how to change your domain name in your Wordpress site.

You can try following the instructions in this [link](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204405334/how-can-i-change-the-domain-name-for-my-wordpress-site) by going to WordPress Dashboard as an administrator. Go to General Settings where you can change URL.

I don't know your version though but it should work.